# Clojurescript (REPL) with Java 11.0.4 – ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

Tags: java, version, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to find my way into ClojureScript, currently following the [modern clojurescript tutorial](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/blob/master/doc/second-edition/tutorial-01.md) using boot as my build tool. Unfortunately I keep running into a Java ClassNotFoundException concerning `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`. Googling only reveals a known problem with the switch from Java 8 to 9. I'm running openJDK 11.0.4 however, so that's hardly my case.

Here's what happened so far. Initially I had no luck compiling Clojurescript at all. I would get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter, compiling:(cljs/closure.clj:1:1)
```

I was able to get around that problem by specifying the ClojureScript version  adding `[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.520"]` to my build.boot file, which currently looks as follows:

```
(set-env!
 :source-paths #{"src/cljs"}
 :resource-paths #{"html"}

 :dependencies '[
                 [adzerk/boot-cljs   "2.1.5" :scope "test"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.520"]
                 [pandeiro/boot-http "0.8.3"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.13"]
                 [adzerk/boot-reload "0.6.0"]
                 [adzerk/boot-cljs-repl   "0.4.0"]
                 [cider/piggieback"0.4.1" :scope "test"]
                 [weasel "0.7.0" :scope "test"]
                 [nrepl "0.6.0" :scope "test"]
                 ])

(require '[adzerk.boot-cljs :refer [cljs]]
         '[pandeiro.boot-http :refer [serve]]
         '[adzerk.boot-reload :refer [reload]]
         '[adzerk.boot-cljs-repl :refer [cljs-repl start-repl]])
```

The problem now is back with a vengeance though within the ClojureScript REPL. I successfully connect to the nREPL started by boot getting into the `boot.user` Namespace (I use the following boot command to start the nREPL `boot serve -d target watch reload cljs-repl cljs target` and connect to it via `boot repl -c`).

To my understanding this opens an ordinary Clojure REPL not a ClojureScript REPL. Trying to start the latter by typing `(start-repl)` gives me almost the exact same error as the one above. Only that it was trying to compile `org/httpkit/server.clj:1:1` rather than `cljs/closure.clj:1:1`.

**To me it seems that the ClojureScript REPL wants to use some default Clojurescript version which apparently differs from the one specified in the `build.boot` file**. I don't really understand either why I had to deviate from the tutorial by specifying the ClojureScript version there in the first place.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

Best to all of you

Oliver

### Addenda:

My System: ubuntu 18.04

My boot.properties:

```
#http://boot-clj.com
#Tue Sep 17 12:18:55 CEST 2019
BOOT_VERSION=2.8.3
BOOT_CLOJURE_VERSION=1.8.0
BOOT_CLOJURE_NAME=org.clojure/clojure
```

Comment: Ok, I've found a solution that feels more like workaround though: I had to add yet another dependency to my build.boot:

`[http-kit "2.3.0"]`
I still feel there must be something wrong under the hood if I have to specify these manually while tutorial doesn't even mention them… Why would my setup default to apparently deprecated versions of libs (the tutorial is a bit dated)?

Answer (score 0):

I realize you've already a solution to this relatively old question, but I wanted to let you know that the problem is actually stated right there in your title.

The [Java EE and Corba modules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-F640FA9D-FB66-4D85-AD2B-D931174C09A3) were all removed from Java in version 11 and require the addition of third-party libraries for support. In the Java world, this was and remains a stumbling block to upgrade for many legacy projects and applications.